# Change the spatial input dimension during training

Tags: tensorflow

I am training a yolov4 (fully convolutional) in tensorflow 2.3.0.

I would like to change the spatial input shape of the network during training, to further adjust the weights to different scales.

Is this possible?

EDIT:
I know of the existence of darknet, but it suffers from some very specific augmentations I use and have implemented in my repo, that is why I ask explicitly for tensorflow.

To be more precisely about what I want to do.

I want to train for several batches at `Y1xX1xC` then change the input size to `Y2xX2xC` and train again for several batches and so on.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible. In the past people trained several networks for different scales but the current state-of-the-art approach is feature pyramids.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.03144.pdf

Another great candidate is to use dilated convolution which can learn long distance dependencies among pixels with varying distance. You can concatenate the outputs of them and the model will then learn which distance is important for which case

https://towardsdatascience.com/review-dilated-convolution-semantic-segmentation-9d5a5bd768f5

Comment: YOLOv4 already uses feature pyramids, still resizing the network during runtime is somewhat the same as augmenting the scale of the image, but in a more natural way. VOLOv2 (or v3 can't really recall showed that) and as @Zabir Al Nazi says in YOLOv4 darknet this is possible and I would like to have the same in tf2

Answer (score 2):

It's important to mention which TensorFlow repository you're using. You can definitely achieve this. The idea is to keep the fixed spatial input dimension in a single batch.

But even better approach is to use the darknet repository from AlexeyAB: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet

Just set, `random = 1` https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/cfg/yolov4.cfg [line 1149]. It will train your network with different spatial dimensions randomly.

One thing you can do is, start your training with AlexeyAB repo with random=1 set, then take the trained weights file to tensorflow for fine-tuning.

Comment: I edit my question, I use tensorflow 2.3.0. Yes I would do it like in darknet, keep the resolution for 10 - 20 batches, then resize the network. 
I am using some very specific copy-paste augmentations during training and it would for me too heavy to implement them in C, hence I chose a yolov4 tensorflow repo.

Comment: Could you maybe eleborate on how this can be achieved in tf2?